# Problems creating TRIGGER in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am first time using trigger concept in my MYSQL workbench like below query,

First I created **people** table by using below query,

```
CREATE TABLE people (age INT, name varchar(150));
```

Then I used below query for trigger

```
DELIMITER 
CREATE TRIGGER agecheck BEFORE INSERT ON raptor1_5.people FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.age < 0 THEN SET NEW.age = 0; END IF;

DELIMITER ;
```

But **agecheck** trigger not creating to **people** table. Its does not show any error message when I run this query.

Here is my table images,

[image]

Updated :  based on the answer

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this.

```
USE `raptor1_5`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS raptor1_5.agecheck$$
USE `raptor1_5`$$
CREATE TRIGGER agecheck BEFORE INSERT ON people 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 IF NEW.age < 0 THEN 
   SET NEW.age = 0; 
 END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It tells which schema to use for the session you are in. Even  though if you try to execute to create a trigger without USING a schema, it should give the error that 'no database selected'

Comment: It was most likley not using any `SCHEMA` , also, try again like this now, se if it doesnt work.

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER agecheck BEFORE INSERT ON raptor1_5.people ` Ive added the database name.

Comment: Nice explanation.I understand the problem. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The standard trigger syntax should be as

```
DELIMITER  //

CREATE TRIGGER agecheck BEFORE INSERT ON raptor1_5.people 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 IF NEW.age < 0 THEN 
   SET NEW.age = 0; 
 END IF;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

The above is when you run on mysql cli, however in phpmyadmin or workbench check if you have an option to set the delimiter if yes choose that and remove the delimiter part from the above.

Comment: Still its not working. Its shows like Executing Query... but nothing happens

Comment: Maybe add a delete trigger if exists before?

Comment: @KayNelson i cant get you

Comment: Add this before the `CREATE TRIGGER` ....... `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS raptor1_5.agecheck//`

Comment: @KayNelson check my updated question. I tried this query but nothing happen